Sequelize Postgres - Multiple Interdependent Queries As One
Is is possible to call two queries that run as if they are a single query. Ie. Both queries need to be successful or both fail. I note that the two queries are completely independent, just have a common trigger event.
I am trying to avoid the complexity of coding the posting of each individually, then checking, then rolling back etc....if there is a error on one of them.
I seem to recall that postgres has this functionality but can't locate it again in the several thousand page manual.
FYI, I am running sequelize on node with postgres as the database.
Thanks
Just hoping to be pointed in the right direction....does functionality exist?

Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images. It is possible they can be combined, but being completely independent perhaps unlikely. But it is impossible to answer with the queries and DDL.

Do you speak about transactions by any chance?

@Anatoly : Thank you, you nailed it, was right in front of me!

The answer is quite straight forward, oh the shame! > transactions:
Postgres: Link to manual
Sequelize: Link to manual
Sample code snippet from the PG manual:
BEGIN;
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance - 100.00
    WHERE name = 'Alice';
-- etc etc
COMMIT;

In summary, it's as simple as calling the queries and then committing:
